# Firebase App (multiple firebase app ) - Create Firestore for same firebase configuration in Isolate and Main app

Tags: firebase

I have 2 firebase datastore instances (can be many) . I am using isolate for certain processes.

Now I have a case where I need to use the same datastore (not the main firebase datastore) in both isolate and main app.

I am able to create the FirebaseFirestore using :FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: app!) in isolate (lets say AppName used is A001)

but when i do the same in Main app for A001, i get error - App already existing , also If i try to look Firebase.apps , i am not able to see the app name

Any help